# Flutter redux How to perform polling

Tags: redux, dart, flutter

`Redux` seems to be a very nice architecture for mobile app development. However, mobile apps have some features that are not common for web apps.

In my case, I would like to start long polling /monitoring location/tracking file system (any action that watches some external state) after the start of some particular screen and stop when the screen is closed.

Let's say we have a function, that can emit multiple events over time.

```dart
Stream<Event>monitor();
```

I would like to listen to the function only when some particular screen is active.

What is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have 3 pages: 'PageHome.dart', 'Page1.dart', 'Page2.dart'.

1. Create another dart file 'GlobalVariables.dart', create a class gv inside this file, create static redux 'stores' for the three pages.
2. create static var strCurPage in gv.
3. suppose each page has a variable that is to be changed by an external event, declare them in gv as static var also.

Codes in GlobalVariables.dart:

```
import 'package:redux/redux.dart';

enum Actions {
  Increment
} 


// The reducer, which takes the previous count and increments it in response to an Increment action.
int reducerRedux(int intSomeInteger, dynamic action) {
  if (action == Actions.Increment) {
    return intSomeInteger + 1;
  }
  return intSomeInteger;
}

class gv {
  static Store<int> storePageHome =
    new Store<int>(reducerRedux, initialState: 0);
  static Store<int> storePage1 =
    new Store<int>(reducerRedux, initialState: 0);
  static Store<int> storePage2 =
    new Store<int>(reducerRedux, initialState: 0);
  static String strCurPage = 'PageHome';
  static String strPageHomeVar = 'PageHomeInitialContent';
  static String strPage1Var = 'Page1InitialContent';
  static String strPage2Var = 'Page2InitialContent';
}
```

3. Import 'GlobalVariables.dart' in all other dart files.
4. Before navigate to a new page, e.g. from PageHome to Page1, set:

gv.strCurPage = 'Page1';

5. Inside your monitor function, if an external event happens, say, change the values of the variables in Page1 and Page2 (But user currently navigating in Page1):

```
void thisFunctionCalledByExternalEvent(strPage1NewContent, strPage2NewContent) {
  gv.strPage1Var = strPage1NewContent;
  gv.strPage2Var = strPage2NewContent;

  if (gv.strCurPage == 'Page1') {
    // Dispatch storePage1 to refresh Page 1
    storePage1.dispatch(Actions.Increment);
  } else if (gv.strCurPage == 'Page2') {
    // Dispatch storePage2 to refresh Page 2
    storePage2.dispatch(Actions.Increment);
  } else {
    // Do not need to refresh page if user currently navigating other pages.
    // so do nothing here
  }
}
```

I don't know whether this is the best way, but using redux and GlobalVariables.dart, I can:

1. know which page the user is currently navigating.
2. change the content of a page even when the user is not at that page when the event fires.  (But the content will be shown when the user navigate to that page later)
3. force the user to go to a specific page no matter which page the user is navigating, when the event fires.